# How to say "the go-to something" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

In English "go-to" is an informal adjective with a meaning close to "the reliable choice that comes as first option". To illustrate the concept better, here are some definitions and examples for "go-to":

> - being a person who can be turned to for expert knowledge, advice, or reliable performance, especially in a crucial situation:
>     *He's our **go-to** guy in a budget crisis.*
> - noting something that can always be relied on to bring satisfaction, success, or good results:
>     *my **go-to** recipe for cheesecake.*
>
> <sup>[Dictionary.Com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/go-to)</sup>
>
> - used to describe the best person to deal with a particular problem or do a particular thing, or the best place to get a particular thing or service:
>     *For 20 years, Wild Mountain was the **go-to** store for outdoor enthusiasts.*
>
> <sup>[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-to)</sup>
>
> - relied on and regularly turned to for expert knowledge, skill, or performance:
>     *Brown became the **go-to** researcher for genetic conundrums.*
> - regularly or repeatedly chosen or employed for reliably good results:
>     *A waitress came by and Reacher ordered his **go-to** breakfast, which was coffee plus a short stack of pancakes with eggs, bacon, and maple syrup.*
>
> <sup>[merriam-websterdictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-to)</sup>

The two neurons in my head have been thinking for a while and could not come with anything that would carry the same meaning in Spanish. One thought of "por defecto", but the other discarded it since "by default" has a different meaning than "go-to".

While a "go-to" option can easily become a default option due to its merit, they are not the same thing.

"By default" or "default option" carries the connotation of a preselected option when no alternative has been specified.

A "go-to" option denotes a person or thing that may be relied on or is regularly sought out in a particular situation (probably *over many other well known options*), while a "default" option denotes that it's been just preselected for convenience.

What would be the best way of translating or conveying "go-to" in Spanish?

Comment: *Referente* or *de referencia* maybe?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to propose *[infalible](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LUFuiMu)*:

> 1. adj. Que no puede errar.
>   2. adj. Seguro, cierto, indefectible.

Maybe it does not fit perfectly with every example, but consider these sentences:

> Fulano es infalible en situaciones de crisis.
>   Tengo una receta de tarta de queso que es infalible.
>   Richard pidió su desayuno infalible.

Nonetheless for the rest of examples another word may be needed. As proposed before, *de referencia* may suit here:

> Wild Mountain era la tienda de referencia entonces.
>   Brown se convirtió en el investigador de referencia.

Comment: Respondida desde un hotel vacacional de Punta Umbría mientras veo con la familia una adaptación infantil teatral de _Mamma mía!_ :-D

Comment: Charlie - ¡Mamma mía!

Comment: "De referencia" es la mejor respuesta al menos en español de Europa.

Answer (score 1):

I like several of the terms proposed. I agree with some of the answers that a different expression might be required according to the context. Here are some other words or phrases that could work:

- ideal
- de cajón / de paso obligado / de consulta obligada (Ser de cajón una cosa significa "ser regular y corriente". Fuente: https://www.fundacionlengua.com/es/cajon/art/207/)
- "caballito de batalla" (https://sigificadoyorigen.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/caballito-de-batalla/)
- al que siempre recurro

Some major recast may be required for the sentences to work with the expressions above:

- He's our go-to guy in a budget crisis: es la persona a la que siempre recurrimos ante un problema presupuestario
- my go-to recipe for cheesecake: esta receta es mi caballito de batalla cuando de cheesecake se trata
- For 20 years, Wild Mountain was the go-to store for outdoor enthusiasts: [...] fue/era la tienda de paso obligado para los adictos al/fanáticos del aire libre
- Brown became the go-to researcher for genetic conundrums: [...] el investigador de consulta obligada [...]
- A waitress came by and Reacher ordered his go-to breakfast, which was coffee plus a short stack of pancakes with eggs, bacon, and maple syrup: [...] su desayuno habitual [...]

Comment: Las traducciones son una buena aportación. Quizá en español el término usado para "go-to" depende un poco más del contexto. El uso de "al que siempre recurro" me parece muy buena propuesta, aunque no sea de por sí un único adjetivo.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the adjective *recomendado* or the verb *recomendar*, modifying the expression accordingly to spanish gammatical usage, because the definition of the equivalent english word *recommend* fits perfectly with the 'go-to' sense of *endorse or present as worthy of acceptance* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recommend)). Using Gustavson's examples:

- Fulano es el analista recomendado cuando hay crisis con el
  presupuesto.
- Es la receta que recomiendo para este tipo de pastel.
- Durante 20 años, Wild Mountain fue la tienda más recomendada para
  conseguir equipo de excursión.
- Brown ha sido el científico que recomendamos para entender problemas de genética.
- Llegó una mesera y Reacher pidió el desayuno que siempre recomendaba: panqués,
  tocino y huevo revuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "mejor" could work, it's something like "the best", so you can say:

> - My go-to recipe for cheesecake.
> - He's our go-to guy in a budget crisis
> - Wild Mountain was the go-to store for outdoor enthusiasts.

as:

> - Mi mejor receta para la tarta de queso.
> - El es nuestro mejor tipo para una crisis financiera
> - Wild Mountain era la mejor tienda para los entusiastas del aire libre

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es *favorito*.  Si quieres algo más preciso, pero bastante universal, propongo

> **en el que más confío**

Tus ejemplos:

- Fulano es el analista en el que más confiamos cuando hay crisis con el presupuesto.
- Es la receta en la que más confío para este tipo de pastel.
- Durante 20 años, Wild Mountain fue la tienda más confiable para conseguir equipo de excursión.
- Brown ha sido nuestro científico en el que más confiamos para entender problemas de genética.
- Llegó una mesera y Reacher pidió el desayuno en el que más confiaba, panqués, tocino y huevo revuelto.

El origen de esta propuesta: estaba pensando en la recomendación que muchas veces se da para manejar problemas como la angustia o la rabia en la escuela:

- Student will be given a laminated pass to visit his Go To Person on a self-determined basis.

Esta persona la escoge el estudiante mismo, por ser la persona en la que más confía.

Comment: I would say `Brown ha sido el científico en el que más confiamos para entender problemas de genética` rather than `...nuestro científico...` which sounds redundant.

Comment: I didn't find the word `panqué` in the dictionary. I guess you are referring to `panqueque` (https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ri6m9md). Where is the word `panqué` used?

Comment: I also believe that `huevos revueltos` sounds better than `huevo revuelto`, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @VladimirNul - In this answer I put the focus on how to express the idea of a "go to" person, place, etc., rather than a perfect translation of each word in the example sentences.  Please feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: Could you please confirm if the word `panqué` has a regional use somewhere? At least it's not in my domain but I don't know all regional differences.

Comment: @VladimirNul - I've been away from Mexico for some time.  I can't verify that these two words (pancake and panqué) match up exactly.  I do see pictures of *panqué* in Google Images, but most often, they look like *pound cake*, baked in a loaf pan, rather than something poured as batter onto a griddle and flipped over.  Again, I invite you to edit the answer. // Would you like to add an entry to [¿Quiénes somos?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2586/9385) ?